# Qtp code : Download attachment from eml file

Tags: download, attachment, qtp, eml, microfocus

I am getting issues while downloading png attachment from the eml file using qtp code.

Downloaded File is not correct attachment.

Below is the code.

```
' Define the path to your EML file
emlFilePath = "C:\path\to\your\email.eml"

' Create a File System Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Check if the EML file exists
If fso.FileExists(emlFilePath) Then
    ' Open the EML file
    Set emlFile = fso.OpenTextFile(emlFilePath, 1)

    ' Read the content of the EML file line by line
    Do Until emlFile.AtEndOfStream
        line = emlFile.ReadLine

        ' Check if the line contains an attachment
        If InStr(1, line, "Content-Disposition: attachment;", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            ' Extract the attachment filename
            attachmentFilename = Mid(line, InStrRev(line, "filename=") + 10)

            ' Remove quotes and any leading or trailing spaces
            attachmentFilename = Replace(attachmentFilename, """", "")
            attachmentFilename = Trim(attachmentFilename)

            ' Copy the attachment to a desired location
            ' For example, to copy it to the desktop
            destinationPath = "C:\Users\<your_username>\Desktop\" & attachmentFilename
            fso.CopyFile emlFilePath, destinationPath

            ' Exit the loop after copying the attachment
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

    ' Close the EML file
    emlFile.Close
Else
    MsgBox "EML file not found: " & emlFilePath
End If

' Clean up
Set fso = Nothing

' Define the path to your EML file
emlFilePath = "C:\path\to\your\email.eml"

' Create a File System Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Check if the EML file exists
If fso.FileExists(emlFilePath) Then
    ' Open the EML file
    Set emlFile = fso.OpenTextFile(emlFilePath, 1)

    ' Read the content of the EML file line by line
    Do Until emlFile.AtEndOfStream
        line = emlFile.ReadLine

        ' Check if the line contains an attachment
        If InStr(1, line, "Content-Disposition: attachment;", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            ' Extract the attachment filename
            attachmentFilename = Mid(line, InStrRev(line, "filename=") + 10)

            ' Remove quotes and any leading or trailing spaces
            attachmentFilename = Replace(attachmentFilename, """", "")
            attachmentFilename = Trim(attachmentFilename)

            ' Copy the attachment to a desired location
            ' For example, to copy it to the desktop
            destinationPath = "C:\Users\<your_username>\Desktop\" & attachmentFilename
            fso.CopyFile emlFilePath, destinationPath

            ' Exit the loop after copying the attachment
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

    ' Close the EML file
    emlFile.Close
Else
    MsgBox "EML file not found: " & emlFilePath
End If

' Clean up
Set fso = Nothing
```

Try this code but code is not working. Expected to get eml file attachment to saved in folder

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the exact issue is? Currently it's unclear whether you get an error or download something else than needed.

Comment: I tried to use above code but it is not downloading attachment from the eml file. It is not giving any error but not able to download attachment

Comment: Have you looked into the server logs?

Comment: Eml file is saved on the desktop folder. No need to check server logs